# jqgrid toolbar filter parameters in link with .asmx web service

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid along with toolbar filter(search). In the server side I have a .asmx web service that is invoked after binding jqgrid to it.

When jqgrid is loaded in the first time the parameters that are sent to web method are:
_search: true
nd: 1384937982166
page: 1
rows: 10
sidx: ""
sord: "desc"

When I enters some text in filter textbox above each column(for example Owner column) the parameters that are sent to web method are something like this:
Owner:"sample"
_search: true
nd: 1384937982166
page: 1
rows: 10
sidx: ""
sord: "desc"

So far so good. But when I clear textbox to load all data without any filtering the parameter "Owner" is not sent to server and I get the following error:
***"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027Owner\u0027."***

So what signature should I use in server side to handle filtering for all columns of grid?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following: ASMX web service *require* that **all parameters of the method always be sent** in every request to the server. jqGrid (in case of usage [toolbar filter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching) or [searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching)) on the other side send filter information (like Owner:"sample") only if the filter is set.

To fix the problem you can extend parameters, which will be send to the server, with `Owner` (or other) inside of `serializeGridData` callback. For example

```js
serializeGridData: function (postData) {
    if (postData.Owner=== undefined) postData.Owner = null;
    return JSON.stringify(postData);
}
```

or

```js
serializeGridData: function (postData) {
    return JSON.stringify($.extend(true, {Owner: null}, postData));
}
```

One more remark. If you have many columns in the grid then you will have to include many parameters (one additional parameter per column) in the ASMX Web Method. It seems to me not nice. You should consider to use `stringResult: true` option of [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching#calling_convention). It follows changing of the format how the parameters will be send to the server. In case of usage `stringResult: true` option jqGrid send **one parameter** with fixed name `filters` to the server. The value of the parameter is JSON string described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching#options). In the case you can deserialize `filters` from JSON to object on the server.

One more important remark. I recommend you consider to use `loadonce: true` option of the grid. If you have not so many total rows in the dataset the usage of the option is very practical. In the case the server don't need to implement server side paging, sorting and filtering of the data. Instead of that the web method should returns **all data at once** and jqGrid will implement paging, sorting and filtering for you.

Comment: Thanks Oleg; your answers helped me